# Problem in my ROS answers profile

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot see the option "post a comment" in most of the places. For example, I posted a question few mins ago. I got two answers for that but I am unable to see the option post a comment below the answers. But I can see the comment option below my question. So, I would like to know how to solve this problem.?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45872/problem-in-my-ros-answers-profile/) by [chris_chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2965/chris_chris/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the problem is that you do not have enough karma yet. I don't know why the comment function is restricted though. Probably to prevent spam.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_chris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2965/chris_chris/) on 2012-10-17**:
yes, now the problem is solved. This is due to that I do not have enough karma. Now, I am able to do comment in all answers